# scanf is triggering a breakpoint

Tags: io, fatal-error, scanf

I am currently in an animation course and we are attempting to create a skeletal mesh from a txt file.  We are using assimp (a free asset importer) to do the loading.  The text file is saving the information properly using fprintf, but when I try to load the information using fscanf (or fscanf_s) my program triggers a breakpoint inside the stdio.h file on the following line (1059).

return __stdio_common_vfscanf (
        _CRT_INTERNAL_LOCAL_SCANF_OPTIONS,
        _Stream, _Format, _Locale, _ArgList);)

After hitting continue I get the following exception.
"An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal."

Here is the code that is triggering the error.

```
uint32_t meshCount;
fscanf(modelFile, "NumMeshes = %d ", &meshCount);
```

Am I doing something wrong with fscanf?  I feel like this is exactly how I've used it in the past.  I must be missing something.

Thanks in advance for any help.